# post back the checkbox value in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model as below

```
public class security
    {  
    public long id { get; set; }
    public long user_id { get; set; }
    public long submenu_id { get; set; }
    public long module_id { get; set; }
    public long flag { get; set; }
    public string module { get; set; }
    public string submenu { get; set; }
  }
```

in which `flag` will be `1` if the user has access to that menu else `0`

I am able to show this in a view using pagedlist

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr class="">
<td>
@if (item.flag == 1)
{
<input type="checkbox" name="flags[]" checked="checked" id="@item.id" value="1" />
}
else
{
<input type="checkbox" name="flags[]"  id="@item.id" value="0" /> 
}
</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.module) </td>
<td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.submenu)</td>
</tr>
}
```

it will give the below output

[image: security]

Here user has access to `5` menus and no access to `1`
Now the admin can change the privileges by checking and un-checking the checkboxes.

My post actionresult signature is as below

```
 public ActionResult security(client_module_security c1,string[] flags)
        {

        }
```

but this is not posting back the values here and the flag string contain only checked numbers. screen shot below

[image: module]
[image: flags]

Please correct me if my logic is bad. What changes to be done in-order to update the same?

Comment: Because you give each checkbox a value of `1` or '0'. Change it to `value="@item.id"` and then you will get the ID's of the checked checkboxes

Comment: And if your wanting to post back values for  `security`, then you need to generate form controls for the properties of `security`

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok got it..value="@item.id" will give all the id which had checked..so it can be updated as 1 and not in the array can be updated as 0..thanks..post it as answer..i will mark it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Model:

```
public class security
{  
    public long id { get; set; }
    public long user_id { get; set; }
    public long submenu_id { get; set; }
    public long module_id { get; set; }
    public bool flag { get; set; }
    public string module { get; set; }
    public string submenu { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@for(var i = 0; i<Model.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m[i].id)
   <tr class="">    
     <td>    
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m[i].flag)
     </td>
     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].module) </td>
     <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].submenu)</td>
   </tr>
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult security(IList<security> model)
        {
                //each one of the items in your model will have Id an flag property filled with data
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

The values of all your checkboxes are either `0` or `1` because you set them using `<input .. value="1" />` or `<input .. value="0" />` (and since only checked checkboxes post back, your values in the controller are always `1`). Instead, set the `value` attribute to the `id` of the item

```
<input type="checkbox" name="flags[]" checked="checked" value ="@item.id" />
```

The `string[] flags` parameter will now contain an array of the ID's of all checked items.

Comment: thanks for the answer i upvoted it..the answer by Alex is also fine for me ..thanks for the help

Comment: Always better to use a view model representing exactly what you want to display/edit :)

Comment: so below answer is more gud?

Comment: Not sure about _gud_ - but its better :) - except I would change `flag` to something more descriptive such as `bool IsSelected` and the view model would not need properties for `user_id`, `submenu_id` and `module_id` since your not using them in the view